# function which allows only name arguments

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, arguments, cookbook

I read a solution in the Python Cookbooks for creating a function that only allows name arguments. I wrote my own code to try it out:

```
class Reporter(object):
    def __init__(self, *, testline=None, sw_ver= None, directory=None):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__"
    r = Reporter()
```

However the interpreter shows this error:

```
File "Reporter.py", line 6
    def __init__(self, *, testline=None, sw_ver= None, directory=None):
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is it showing this?

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot have a `star` alone, what are you trying to do with that?

Comment: Are you sure you copied from the book correctly? Maybe the book had a name(variable name) after the star before the comma ?

Comment: [IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/2dui9sx.jpg[/IMG] this is code from this book

Comment: Which Python version do you use? Which Python version is the book for?

Answer (score 9):

The code you are using **is** valid syntax but for *python3* so the book must be using python3 syntax, it allows  keyword arguments only, [pep-3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/):

[python 3 new syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#new-syntax)

> You can also use a bare * in the parameter list to indicate that you don’t accept a variable-length argument list, but you do have keyword-only arguments.

Using your code and passing a non keyword in python 3 would error but for a different reason:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b4df44fa1e0c> in <module>()
      1 if __name__ == "__main__":
----> 2         r = Reporter(4)
      3 

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Once you use a keyword it works fine:

```
In [4]: if __name__ == "__main__":
             r = Reporter(testline=4)
   ...:
```

Using a function with the same syntax would maybe give a more obvious error:

```
def f(*, foo=None, bar=None):
    return foo, bar


In [6]: f(4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a122d87dbe99> in <module>()
----> 1 f(4)

TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Is is also useful if you want to allow some positional args and have optional keywords args passed but only by name:

```
def f(a,b, *, foo=None, bar=None):
    return a, b, foo, bar
```

Then passing 3 positional args will error:

```
In [8]: f(1,2,3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-b61741968103> in <module>()
----> 1 f(1,2,3)

TypeError: f() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 5):

I received a recent comment about this answer.
→ Please note it targets python2, since OP explicitly tagged his question with python2.7. For python3, see Padraic Cunningham's answer.

**[original answer]**

You may not use the `*` alone. In the function declaration, it means "unpack any other unnamed argument in this variable", so you have to give it a variable name.

You can achieve what you want by giving it a name, then checking it is empty, like this:

```
class Reporter(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        assert not args, "Reporter.__ini__ only accepts named arguments"
```

Then you'd want to add arguments you can allow, like this:

```
# won't work
def __init__(self, *args, testline=None, sw_ver= None, directory=None):
```

...except *args needs to be at the end. But if you put them at the end, you'll see that you can still pass the other arguments unnamed first.

You have to reverse the logic, and take only kwargs.

```
class Reporter(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        testline = kwargs.pop('testline', None)
        sw_ver = kwargs.pop('sw_ver', None)
        directory = kwargs.pop('directory', None)
        assert not kwargs, 'Unknown arguments: %r' % kwargs
```

Now, if someone tries to give unnamed argments, they will be rejected.

Comment: thanks, but your solution also generate syntax error:   File "Reporter.py", line 6
 
    def __init__(self, *args, testline=None, sw_ver= None, directory=None):
                                                   ^ 
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I only got half-way through my reasoning and got distracted, sorry about that. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

The star operator (`*`) is used for [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). You can't use it as an argument.

You may want to read [Variable-Length Argument Tuples](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Think_Python/Tuples#Variable-length_argument_tuples):

> Functions can take a variable number of arguments. A parameter name
>   that begins with * gathers arguments into a tuple. For example,
>   printall takes any number of arguments and prints them:

```
def printall(*args):
    print args
```

> The gather parameter can have any name you like, but args is
>   conventional. Here’s how the function works:

```
>>> printall(1, 2.0, '3') (1, 2.0, '3')
```

Answer (score 1):

These are a few utility decorators I wrote on a tangent for a Python 2 project I was working on. The exceptions raised mirror, as closely as possible, the ones raised by functions in Python 3 that use the keyword-only arguments syntax.

They don't disallow positional arguments, but they can require/restrict keyword arguments.  You could create another decorator that disallowed positional arguments.

```
import functools

def original_wrapped_function(f):
    try:
        while True:
            f = f.__wrapped__
    except AttributeError:
        return f


def restrict_kwargs(*allowed_keywords):
    def restrict_kwargs_decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(original_wrapped_function(func))
        def restrict_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for keyword in kwargs:
                if keyword not in allowed_keywords:
                    msg = "%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'"
                    raise TypeError(msg % (func.__name__, keyword))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        restrict_wrapper.__wrapped__ = func
        return restrict_wrapper
    return restrict_kwargs_decorator


def require_kwargs(*required_keywords):
    def require_kwargs_decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(original_wrapped_function(func))
        def require_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            missing_keywords = []
            for keyword in required_keywords:
                if keyword not in kwargs:
                    missing_keywords.append(keyword)
            if missing_keywords:
                func_name = func.__name__
                count = len(missing_keywords)
                if count == 1:
                    arg_word = 'argument'
                    missing_keywords_str = "'%s'" % missing_keywords[0]
                else:
                    arg_word = 'arguments'
                    and_join_str = ' and ' if count == 2 else ', and '
                    missing_keywords_str = ', '.join(
                        ("'%s'" % mk) for mk in missing_keywords[:-1])
                    missing_keywords_str = and_join_str.join((
                        missing_keywords_str, ("'%s'" % missing_keywords[-1])))
                msg = "%s() missing %d required keyword-only %s: %s"
                raise TypeError(msg % (func_name, count, arg_word,
                                       missing_keywords_str))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        require_wrapper.__wrapped__ = func
        return require_wrapper
    return require_kwargs_decorator


def exact_kwargs(*exact_keywords):
    def exact_kwargs_decorator(func):
        @restrict_kwargs(*exact_keywords)
        @require_kwargs(*exact_keywords)
        @functools.wraps(original_wrapped_function(func))
        def exact_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        exact_wrapper.__wrapped__ = func
        return exact_wrapper
    return exact_kwargs_decorator
```

Some examples:

```
>>> @restrict_kwargs('five', 'six')
... def test_restrict_kwargs(arg1, arg2, *moreargs, **kwargs):
...     return (arg1, arg2, moreargs, kwargs)
... 
>>> 
>>> @require_kwargs('five', 'six')
... def test_require_kwargs(arg1, arg2, *moreargs, **kwargs):
...     return (arg1, arg2, moreargs, kwargs)
... 
>>> 
>>> @exact_kwargs('five', 'six')
... def test_exact_kwargs(arg1, arg2, *moreargs, **kwargs):
...     return (arg1, arg2, moreargs, kwargs)
... 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> test_restrict_kwargs(1, 2, 3, 4, five=5)
(1, 2, (3, 4), {'five': 5})
>>> 
>>> test_restrict_kwargs(1, 2, 3, 4, five=5, six=6)
(1, 2, (3, 4), {'six': 6, 'five': 5})
>>> 
>>> test_restrict_kwargs(1, 2, 3, 4, five=5, six=6, seven=7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "SO_31939890.py", line 19, in restrict_wrapper
    raise TypeError(msg % (func.__name__, keyword))
TypeError: test_restrict_kwargs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'seven'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> test_require_kwargs(1, 2, 3, 4, five=5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "SO_31939890.py", line 49, in require_wrapper
    missing_keywords_str))
TypeError: test_require_kwargs() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'six'
>>> 
>>> test_require_kwargs(1, 2, 3, 4, five=5, six=6)
(1, 2, (3, 4), {'six': 6, 'five': 5})
>>> 
>>> test_require_kwargs(1, 2, 3, 4, five=5, six=6, seven=7)
(1, 2, (3, 4), {'seven': 7, 'six': 6, 'five': 5})
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> test_exact_kwargs(1, 2, 3, 4, five=5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "SO_31939890.py", line 20, in restrict_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "SO_31939890.py", line 49, in require_wrapper
    missing_keywords_str))
TypeError: test_exact_kwargs() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'six'
>>> 
>>> test_exact_kwargs(1, 2, 3, 4, five=5, six=6)
(1, 2, (3, 4), {'six': 6, 'five': 5})
>>> 
>>> test_exact_kwargs(1, 2, 3, 4, five=5, six=6, seven=7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "SO_31939890.py", line 19, in restrict_wrapper
    raise TypeError(msg % (func.__name__, keyword))
TypeError: test_exact_kwargs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'seven'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

A star (`*`) is not a valid Python 2.7 identifier, it's an operator. I think you made a mistake while copying a code from the cookbook.

However, it's a valid code in Python 3, as Padraic Cunningham [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31940360/4408382).

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.*:

Parameters names derived as variables name laws in any programming languages. but in python 2.* **STAR** sign used before parameters names for [determining special situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters) and single **STAR** sign as a parameter name raising error.

But in python 3.*:

A parameter that equal to **STAR** can't assign any value to this and next position parameters can't give value by position, and only can value by parameter name.